# How can I see changes in Genymotion made in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-emulator, genymotion

I'm trying to use Genymotion virtual machine in Eclipse. I installed several virtual machines, but I'm having problems when I want to see changes made on my app. Every time I add something new to my app, is not showing it up on the emulator. Does anybody know how "refresh" the Genymotion emulator so I can show the changes made in the app?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about the problem? Is the build+install done on the device? What is not updated on your app?

Comment: I tried to update my app adding more titles, text and features but Genymotion is not showing up the changes on the emulator, it just shows me the same things I had before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is coming from the XML resources it could be caused by a refresh that is not done on the Eclipse side. I had this problem a very long time ago. I had to uninstall the app before installing it again.

You can try different manipulations, one of them should solve your problem:

- First, check that your new APK is correctly transfered and installed on the device. Look at the console output for that.
- Or, change a character on a JAVA file and save, before building your app
- You can also clean your project before running your app
- And finally, uninstall your app before installing it